# Build third list of tuples from two sources

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to compare two lists of tuples and create a third list of tuples that contains the highest values of the two:

```
b = [(u'eventId', 0), (u'playerId', 0), (u'expandedMinute', 0), \
(u'second', 0), (u'endY', 00.0), (u'teamId', 0), (u'endX', 00.0), (u'y', 00.0), (u'x', 00.0), \
(u'isTouch', 'Null'), (u'id', 0.0), (u'minute', 0)]

c = [(u'expandedMinute', 93), \
 (u'second', 47), (u'endY', 67.8), (u'teamId', 32), (u'endX', 91.0), \
 (u'y', 83.8), (u'x', 88.1), (u'isTouch', True), (u'id', 2136355953.0), \
 (u'minute', 91)]


d={k:c[k] if k in c and c[k]>b[k] else v for k,v in b.items()}
print [(k, v) for k, v in d.items()]
```

I've done something similar before with a pair of dictionaries and been able to use the logic beginning with 'd =' to get this to work, however it is no longer suitable for my current situation.

The desired output should look like this (the first two tuples, 'eventId' and 'playerId', which are in b, but not c are added to the final list of tuples):

```
[(u'eventId', 0), (u'playerId', 0), (u'expandedMinute', 93), \
 (u'second', 47), (u'endY', 67.8), (u'teamId', 32), (u'endX', 91.0), \
 (u'y', 83.8), (u'x', 88.1), (u'isTouch', True), (u'id', 2136355953.0), \
 (u'minute', 91)]
```

In my scenario 'C' will only ever contain the same as 'B' or a subset of it. It will never contain additional tuple items.

Can anyone assist me with the logic I need to complete my code?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a list of tuples as opposed to a dictionary (possible an `OrderedDict`, if the order matters to you)?

Comment: @DSM yes, because the list of tuples is created from two lists by zipping them.

Comment: That doesn't really explain it, because unless you have a duplicate "key", or care about order, you could just as easily have done `dict(zip(list0, list1))`.  And dictionaries have an `.update` method.

Comment: @DSM i do care about order, yes.

Comment: If you cared about order then your `d = ` line wouldn't have worked, because that's a dictionary comprehension, and dictionaries don't preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

Lists of tuples which look to all the world like key-value pairs scream out for an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).  Assuming you're looking to update the values:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> bd = OrderedDict(b)
>>> cd = OrderedDict(c)
>>> newd = bd.copy()
>>> newd.update(cd)
>>> newd
OrderedDict([(u'eventId', 0), (u'playerId', 0), (u'expandedMinute', 93), (u'second', 47), (u'endY', 67.8), (u'teamId', 32), (u'endX', 91.0), (u'y', 83.8), (u'x', 88.1), (u'isTouch', True), (u'id', 2136355953.0), (u'minute', 91)])
```

But if you insist on a list of tuples:

```
>>> print newd.items()
[(u'eventId', 0), (u'playerId', 0), (u'expandedMinute', 93),
 (u'second', 47), (u'endY', 67.8), (u'teamId', 32),
 (u'endX', 91.0), (u'y', 83.8), (u'x', 88.1), 
 (u'isTouch', True), (u'id', 2136355953.0), (u'minute', 91)]
```